# Python and serial data indexing and slicing

Tags: python, serial-port

The prompt here is to compare the data from the array, the data in indexed from the serial port and is stored in the form of strings, ( which i doubt), My aim is compare the data stored in the arrays from the specific indexes. Looking at the conditions you can get a better idea. The result just executes the last else statement, neglecting the other conditions. What would be the reason? I tried taking out the " " from the integers too.

I'm new to python so not really sure of the method was right.

```
while True:
            line = ser.readline().strip('\n').strip('\r')  
            print "Received: '{}'".format(line)
            datal = line.split(':')
            for i in range(len(datal)):
              print "data[{}]".format(i), datal[i]
              if (datal[1:2] > 27 and datal[0] > 28):
                    x = "Sound above moderate level"
                    y = "temp is too high"
             elif(datal[1:2] > 27 and datal[0]< 27):
                    x = "Sound moderate"
                    y = "Temperature is too high."
             elif(datal[0:1] < 27 and datal[0] > 27):
                    x = "Sound above moderate level"
                    y = "Temperature is moderate"
            else:
                    x = "Ambient sound"
                    y = "Ambient temperature"


            return datal
```

Comment: Can you post the format of serial data or a sample serial data you are getting.

Comment: You're using *Python 2* which is the reason for this unfortunate thing. In Python 3 you'd get a TypeError. You're comparing slices of a list? against integers, which will succeed in Python 2 but will have meaningless results.

Comment: While at it, why wouldn't you switch to Python 3 now?

Comment: @venky__ it is  integer:integer:integer and it continues.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Shift as in? do i have to compile it in a different way? I have python 3 installed on my pc.

Comment: Run them with Python 3. However you need change some other things too. But whereas in Python 2 `'27' > 26` silently results in `True`, in Python 3 `TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()` will be raised...

Comment: What do you expect your conditions `datal[1:2] > 27` et c. to mean? Do you want to test 27 against multiple entries?

Comment: @JohanL I wanted to compare the value between [1:2]

Comment: I still don't get it. Which value is between [1:2]? You have split your values colons, thus you expect to have a single value (coded as strings, however) in each list position, I assume? That would mean values indexed by [1:2] will be only one value, since only the "begin" index is inclusive.

Comment: @JohanL ohh i get it! your right. Its my mistake, but even without the split it gives an error for string and int conversion.

Comment: But you want to split your numbers on colons, I guess. But, then you must convert the resulting strings to integers, before you use them in comparisons, e.g.: `data = [int(value) for value in datal]` and then use `data` values instead of `datal` values in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

using `map` function

```
while True:
    line = ser.readline().strip('\n').strip('\r')  
    print "Received: '{}'".format(line)
    datal = list(map(int,line.split(':')))
    for i in range(len(datal)):
        print "data[{}]".format(i), datal[i]
        if datal[1] > 27 and datal[0] > 28:
            x = "Sound above moderate level"
            y = "temp is too high"
        elif datal[1] > 27 and datal[0]< 27 :
            x = "Sound moderate"
            y = "Temperature is too high."
        elif datal[0] < 27 and datal[0] > 27:
            x = "Sound above moderate level"
            y = "Temperature is moderate"
        else:
            x = "Ambient sound"
            y = "Ambient temperature"

    return datal
```

also

```
data[0:1] selects 0th element == data[0]
data[1:2] selects 1st element == data[1]
data[2:3] selects 2nd element == data[2]
```

you are comparing strings with integers so only the else statement get executed. convert string to an integer.

If you want to compare multiple values use 
`data[0] > 27 and data[1] > 27 and data[2] < 28`

If you are using Linux then you compile the code using `python3 filename.py`

Comment: actually, those `data1[1:2]` must be list slices so this wouldn't work either

Comment: @venki__ i get an error saying " int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' ".

Comment: Nope didn't work. Should I convert it into an integer while reading from the serial port?

Comment: I edited the answer again the thing is I was comparing a slice of list with integer.

Comment: @venky__ what is the python2 version for your edits? I guess that will help as i'm using python 2.